# Create output in Array list

Tags: python

An example of my input is:

```
3->0 0->1 1->2 2->3
```

I need to produce output in an array list

```
{3,0,1,2}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is your input coming from?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We'd love to help but it would be descent of the people asking questions to at least try to solve the problem themselves. There's plenty examples here on SO regarding splitting strings and manipulation raw data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers located before the "arrows" (`->`), here is a solution using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) :

```
>>> list(map(int, re.findall('[0-9](?=->)', '3->0 0->1 1->2 2->3')))
[3, 0, 1, 2]
```

I'm using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert the strings to int.

**More informations on the regex used :**

I'm using a lookahead expression (`(?=->`)) to match only something located before this string : `'->'`.
And what I am looking for is a number between 0 and 9, thanks to the set of characters `[0-9]`.

Please note that this won't match `10` for example. In this case, I need to change the regex to the following : `[0-9]+(?=->)`, to match 1 or more numbers.